# Spring XD recovery semantics

Tags: spring-xd

What are the recovery semantics for Spring XD. I have gone through all the publicly available resources, but still not able get any definite answer.

To elaborate on my question and keep it simple.

a) What happens when a Source fails?

b) What happens when a Processor fails?

c) What happens when a sink fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "fails"; if you mean "fails to process a message",  with processors and sinks, the message bus can be configured with various retry options and, with Rabbit, permanent failures (after retries are exhausted) can be sent to a dead letter exchange/queue (or an ERROR list with REDIS). See [Error Handling (Message Delivery Failures)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#error-handling-message-delivery-failures).

For sources, it depends on the source and the nature of the failure; in general, the error will be reported to the sender in some fashion. However, for some sources, e.g. rabbit, jms; the message may be redelivered.

For all modules, if the container fails, the admin will redeploy its modules if there's another container available.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your answer. Clarifies a lot of things.